# Xuggler NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, xuggler

I am trying to make a simple media player using the following tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aJvPPzhyik

To start off with, I will explain what I have done up to now, I downloaded xuggler without using Apache Maven or Apache Ivy,  I went into version 5.1 and the and downloaded only the xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar, I imported this into eclipse and it worked because I started writing my code and all the media class's had no errors.

I needed a flv file so I just put in any random youtube link into this website http://keepvid.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DvNoKguSdy4Y and got my flv video downloaded to my desktop, now here is where I think the problem is, on the tutorial it show that he has to put this flv video into Xuggle/Workspace/MediaToolsIntro1 but since I just downloaded one jar file I dont have a xuggle folder and only have a jar file on my desktop so I placed it into Users/Me/Workspace/Myjavaproject. I ran the code and got the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

What have I done wrong, when the programmer in the guide video does it he gets a QT file created next to his flv but I get an error, the only difference between me and him is the flv file location.

Comment: Make sure your jar files are there in correct class path

Comment: Do you mean put my flv file inside the src with the class's? because I tried that and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: No! not the flv file.The jar file/folders you downloaded, should be there in your class plath.Are you using some IDE? net beans or something?

Comment: I am using eclipse, is class path the environmental variables? because I have only ever set that once and that was when I was making the path for JDK. Does xuggler also require a path?

Comment: Yes,i am talking about the environmental variables.So,same way you have to add those in your class path.But if you are using eclipse,go to your library folder,and add those jar file which you have downloaded

Comment: Where can I find my library folder, is that the one I set when I first got eclipse? I set it at Users/me/workspace.

Comment: Wait,i'll google it and tell you :p

Comment: I found it, I realised that I had already imported my jar file into there when I started the project.

Comment: see this link http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java).
OK,then please provide full exception stack trace

Comment: The problem I think is caused by where I am placing the flv file, in the youtube tutorial it is placed in a xuggler folder but since I only got a jar I dont have any folder like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22591/discussion-between-joey-rohan-and-mamta-rani)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Suggest you to download all `jar` files and place them in your Class path.

Comment: were you able to find the site to download all jars?